# Pass model property to Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Edit: I found the answer, but it meant abandoning the use of HtmlActionlink in favor of doing this (the "blah" parameters from my original post now being subbed in for what I actually needed):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("LinkedDetails", 
                     new 
                         { 
                           controller = "LGDetails", 
                           findByString = item.AccounNumber
                         })">@item.LastName</a>
```

This does exactly what I want.  Trying to accomplish the same thing with HtmlActionLink results in one error or another no matter what I tried:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.LastName, 
                 "../LGDetails/LinkedDetails", 
                 new 
                    { 
                      controller = "LinkedDetails", 
                      findByString = item.AccounNumber 
                    })
```

result: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: linkText

Trying like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.LastName  .....
```

### Result:

> > System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'LastName' and no extension method 'LastName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

etc etc.  Always one of those errors regardless.

And yes, I tried every single thing suggested here, and an equal number of other things found elsewhere (which is how I found the answer I did use, it was posted by another person having the same problem).

---

Despite a lot of searching, I can't seem to figure out how to do what seems like it should be basic.

This works fine:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
```

But I want to display the LastName field as the linked text inside an Html.ActionLink like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.LastName, "blah", "blah")
```

But nothing works.  Doing it like the above gives me a compilation error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly

I've tried it like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName), "blah", "blah")
```

and other variations thereof where it is nested.  That doesn't work either (won't compile) with the error "no overload method for actionlink.."

I feel like this should be simple.  Yes, I'm very new to C# and MVC.

Comment: Sorry, the error I get when doing this:

@Html.ActionLink(item.LastName, "blah", "blah")

is actually 

Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: linkText 

I got the other error about specifying the type arguments specifically while trying something else.  I forget what I was trying.

Comment: Why are you using `modelItem => item.LastName` rather than `item => item.LastName`? You're currently ignoring the lambda expression parameter entirely...

Comment: item => item.Lastname does not work in any capacity.  Even in the htmldisplayfor it throws an error "A local variable named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'item', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: Then change the parameter name! Use `modelItem => modelItem.LastName`. My point still stands...

Answer (score 4):

you need to use this overload of `Html.ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(string LinkText,string ActionName,string ControllerName)
```

do like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.LastName, "ActionName","ControllerName")
```

**Updated:**

then do like this, as your Model is IEnumerable:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{

@Html.ActionLink(item.LastName, "ActionName","ControllerName")

}
```

If Model is Single like this:

```
@model MyCompany.LGCustData
```

then it should be lke this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.LastName, "ActionName","ControllerName")
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.ActionLink(@Model.AccounNumber....)`  works in case someone ends up here just like me.

Answer (score 0):

this is a breaf description of how you should use an actionlink

```
Html.ActionLink("link title", 
                "ActionMethod",  
                 "ControllerName",  
                    null, // <-- Route arguments.
                    null  // <-- htmlArguments
)
```

try something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model.LastName, "actionMethod","controllerName",new{Model.LastName});
```

*if the case you want to add some parameters to your route, following the standard convention:

```
/controller/action/parameter
```

otherwise

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model.LastName, "actionMethod","controllerName");
```

Comment: Sorry, but none of these things work.  All give me one error or another.

This:

@Html.DisplayFor(Model.LastName, "actionMethod","controllerName");

Gives me the error "...does not contain a definition for 'LastName'..."

Comment: @Html.ActionLink(item =>item.LastName, "blah", "blah")

This also does not work.  "Cannot convert lamda expression to type string"

Why is it so hard to just make a dynamic property into linked text? Maybe I'll just forget it and stick a link next to it that just says "details" likeyou get when you let VS automatically create the index, create, edit, detail views.  Maybe VS knows something I don't which is why it doesn't make the dynamic item into a link to begin with.

Comment: have you defined your model using "@model" at the top of the page? that model should contain your definition for "LastName", something like "@model MyNamespace.Models.MyModel"

Comment: Yes.  Defined at the top.

Everything was auto generated by VS.  Standard index, details, edit, create & delete views based off the model.

They all work fine "out of the box".  I am now in the process of manipulating them more and more to teach myself newer and newer things.  

But this one thing, which seems like it should be extremely easy and downright commonly done, is defying success.

Comment: can you update your question with your model definition?

Comment: My case i do want to sent a particular row model to controller .I tried to send the model value like this unable to receive the value.  View :   @Html.ActionLink("Reject","Reject", "Admin", new { reservationObj = item }) Controller : public ActionResult Reject(Models.Reservations reservationObj)
        {
            bool isreject = false;
            try
            {
               

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            //TO DO: Implement approriate logic
            return View();
        }

Answer (score 0):

For me I simply convert the "dynamic text" before in a string with `String.Format()` function like this

```
<ul>
@foreach (var user in ViewBag.users )
{
    string complete_name = String.Format("{0} {1}", user.Firstname, user.Lastname);
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(complete_name, "Details", new { Id = user.Id })</li>
}
</ul>
```

On my computer it works very fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
@Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName).ToHtmlString(), "blah", "blah")
```